# Play framework 2, how to use execution context in Java?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

The official documents only describe how to use it in scala. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools.

```
Future {
  // Some blocking or expensive code here
}(Contexts.myExecutionContext)
```

I can get the excutionContext like:

```
ExecutionContext myExecutionContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("my-context");
```

But how to add it in the code blow?

```
return async(
    future(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
              return doSth();
        }).map(new F.Function<String,Result>() {
           public Result apply(String i) {
              return ok(i);
           }
        })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer should be：

```
    ExecutionContext myExecutionContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("my-context");
    return async(
            Akka.asPromise(Futures.future(new Callable<String>() {
              public String call() {
                return doSth();
              }   
            }, myExecutionContext)).map(new F.Function<String,Result>() {
              public Result apply(String i) {
                return ok(i);
              }
            })
    );
```